# Why is this Python while loop not working?

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

I'm trying to count the rows in a file until there's at least 5 rows, and then stop counting.

I can't figure out why this simple `while` loop seems to be generating an infinite loop:

```
    row_count = 0
    while row_count <= 5:
        for row in file_reader:
            row_count += 1
```

Comment: The file_reader variable length might 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop will run to completion first before the `while` gets a chance to test `row_count`.

Break out of the `for` loop instead:

```
row_count = 0
for row in file_reader:
    row_count += 1
    if row_count > 5:
        break
```

You can use `enumerate()` to generate the count:

```
for row_count, row in enumerate(file_reader):
    if row_count > 5:
        break
```

Last, but not least, there is [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

for row in islice(file_reader, 5):
    # only first five lines are iterated over
```